# Best way to display a message for users that came from a specific page on the website?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, get

I have a quick question on the best way to show a particular message to users that navigated to a page via a particular link on the site.

The situation is I have a sidebar on the website and two of the links will point to the same page - one of them used to point to a page containing a form but now I want to change it to point to the same page as another link and display a message for users that clicked this particular link.

I tried changing the htaccess file and using `HTTP_REFERER` but because theses links are in a sidebar on every page that doesn't work - never thought that one through at the time!

Now I have tried simply changing the link and adding a parameter on the end, e.g. `/page.html?question=yes` and then doing the following on the page:

```
if ($_GET['question'] == 'yes')
{
    echo '..................';  
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be working either so I was wondering if anyone had came accross a similar problem and how they went about solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $_GET and Querystring is the best match for you, but I'm not sure your file extension is being processed properly. Try to change .html to .php

Comment: yeah, it's a funny one, for some reason using $_GET etc isn't working - all the extensions are html but the site is all php, I think it's just all renamed via htaccess :(

Comment: yip, just did `echo '<pre>'.var_dump($_GET).'</pre>'; ` and the array is empty.

Comment: If $_GET is not working, then there must some issue with code.

Please paste the code here so we can review it

Comment: Ok then paste the url you are getting with query string

Comment: I managed to get it to work using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead. Thanks for your help.